# How to install iptables when the installed packages are newer than required?

Tags: debian, iptables, package-management

The required packages had installed the newest version:

```
sudo apt install libiptc0   libxtables12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libiptc0 is already the newest version (1.8.5-3~bpo10+1).
libxtables12 is already the newest version (1.8.5-3~bpo10+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
```

Try to install iptables :

```
sudo apt install  iptables
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 iptables : Depends: libiptc0 (= 1.8.2-4) but 1.8.5-3~bpo10+1 is to be installed
            Depends: libxtables12 (= 1.8.2-4) but 1.8.5-3~bpo10+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to install iptables when the installed packages are newer than required?

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.24-1~bpo10+1 (2021-03-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: *Are* you, in fact, using Debian Unstable for some reason?  The error message seems pretty plain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installed libraries are from Buster backports, not Debian 10. Backports repositories aren’t installation candidates by default, so to install the matching `iptables`, you need to enable the appropriate repository:

```
sudo apt install -t buster-backports iptables
```

Alternatively, you could force the libraries to be downgraded:

```
sudo apt install iptables libiptc0/stable libxtables12/stable
```